# Delay in custom metric on AWS Cloudwatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm learning about AWS services and I have a problem with a custom metric on Cloudwatch service.

I have an EC2 instance that has an apache web server and an API with Python Flask. In a specific API's endpoint I've developed a custom metric with boto3 (python), this metric is quite simple: set 1 when it is called. Metric works successfully, I just have the delay issue.

I can see the metric in Cloudwatch AWS Console, but the metric shows the values half an hour later: if I execute the API endpoint at 16:03, i'll see the value at 16:33 exactly.

EC2 instance and custom metric is hosted in us-east-1 region.

As I told, the metric that I developed is quite simple:

```
import boto3
cwatch = boto3.client('cloudwatch', region_name='us-east-1')
cwatch.put_metric_data(
    Namespace='CS',
    MetricData=[{
                'MetricName': 'EC2_Access',
                'Dimensions': [{'Name': 'EC2_Access','Value': 'Num_Accesses'},],
                'Unit': 'None',
                'Value': 1.0
                }
               ])
```

In all the tries that I've made, the delay is 30 min... Why is it happening?

Comment: How are you checking if the metric is there? If you are using the cloudwatch UI, are you changing the view from the default of "Average" to "data points"?

Comment: Yes, i can see my custom metric in Cloudwatch UI, i'm configuring the plot for see the last relative 15 minutes, adding all the point in each minute, updating the plot each minute. When 30 minutes has elapsed, i see the points in the plot...

Comment: Try fetching the data points via the API. That will show if they are really delayed or if it's a problem with the way you have configured the display of the graph.

Comment: API works fine, the endpoint show the expected without delay in the browser. If I run the url-endpoint 4 times in a minute, for example at 17:40 local time, and 6 times in a other minute, for example at 17:42 local time... I'll see the data value  Num_Accesses = 4 at 18:10 local time and 18:12 local time i'll see Num_Accesses = 6 in the plot. The value is correct, but I need to wait half and hour to see the values in my custom metric... In all of times is exactly 30 minutes...

Comment: Try enabling the Live Data in the graph options.

Comment: It was enabled in all tries...